# MEANJS Server controller list function

Tags: meanjs

i have some problems changing my list function in the server controller of my MEANJS app. This is the **export.list** function in the server controller of my module:

```
    exports.list = function(req, res) {
  Wordset.find({ 'user':req.user._id }).sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, wordsets) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.jsonp(wordsets);
    }
  });
};
```

What it does is that it lists all the items from this module in the listview. In this case it shows all Wordset fromt this user. What i would like to change is that it should show Wordsets not depending on the user, but depending on another module (a user can create persons and each person should have his own wordsets). Lets say i have stored the person._id already, what changes do i need to do here to show only the Worsets for this specific person?

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this (ofc. if Wordset has person field):

```
Wordset.find({ 'person': person._id })
```

Comment: i have a wordset ref in the person model and i thought i tried earlier to set to person._id (sorry, didnt wrote this before). The problem is, i think that you need a specific person_id. you need to use something like the person._id from the person that hast been choosen/clicked. so maybe something like a setter in a service?

Comment: so far i got a the person._id onclick set to a variable personId. than i did: `Wordset.find({ 'patient': req.personId })` but it still shows this wordset for every person.

Comment: is it a problem that my person has a ref to wordset and not vice versa?